# Visual Studio Code and Angular: how do I rename folders and component class?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using **Visual Studio Code** for my huge **Angular-4** project.
From time to time I copy components entirely and then modify them.
Components are organized in folders so i end up renaming multiple files and class names.

Is there an extension that does this all at once?

```
my-component-name\
my-component-name\my-component-name.component.cs
my-component-name\my-component-name.component.html
my-component-name\my-component-name.component.css
export class MyComponent
```

Would be handy to just give a new name and renaming would be done everywhere.
Thanks

Comment: https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code/

Comment: Thanks! I know john papa's refactoring with VS Code, but I do not see how to rename a component and all folders get renamed with it. 
Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can try [Move To](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts)

Comment: @Flaugzig, you cant rename files with VS Code's search option.

Comment: You're right. my bad :)

Comment: This works pretty well in webstorm, not sure if it's possible in vscode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now there is a way to rename Angular Component classes and folders in one step from VS Code.

The [Rename Angular Component](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomwhite007.rename-angular-component) extension on Visual Studio Marketplace.

[image: Rename Angular Component in action]

The current release also supports renaming Directives, Services and Route Guards

Comment: hey tom! Thats an old question and I still have no solution. checking out your extension right away 

Comment: Thanks for the stars on Visual Studio Marketplace @PeterFromCologne ! Your comments inspire me to do more.

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience with VSCode, the only way is to reach out to the master Project folder and rename the files/ folders as per your requirement manually while the IDE is closed. Refresh the folder and CTRL+O the folder thereafter from VSCode. This has worked for me.